# Problems with php gettext mo files load

Tags: php, locale, gettext

I have this php code:

```
putenv('LANG=C.UTF-8');
setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, 'C');

bindtextdomain('messages', '/var/www/domain.com/locale/es');
bind_textdomain_codeset('messages', 'UTF-8');
textdomain('messages');
```

My folder locale is `/var/www/domain.com/locale/es/C/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo`

With an echo for each gettext commands, the response is correct (also setlocale to C). I have enabled intl to use `LC_MESSAGES` (verified with `phpinfo()` and `defined('LC_MESSAGES')`)

Into my local environment translations are working fine, but in production server not (PHP 5.4.30).

I have restarted apache, testing other locales, a lot of folder distributions, but any worked.

If I change `setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, 'C')` to `setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, 'C.UTF-8')` setlocale returns false.

How can I debug where is PHP looking for .mo files?

**UPDATE**

Using this code:

```
putenv('LANG=en_US.UTF-8');
setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, 'en_US.UTF-8');

bindtextdomain('messages', '/var/www/domain.com/locale');
bind_textdomain_codeset('messages', 'UTF-8');
textdomain('messages');
```

And folder locale to `/var/www/domain.com/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo` translations are loaded successfully.

But I need to use any locale files installed or not into system (using C as locale). How can I install C.UTF-8? (I have only C) It's possible?

Thanks :)

Comment: You're supposed to bind `/var/www/domain.com/locale` as the domain and set the LANG/locale to `es` or `es.UTF-8`. That locale must also be installed on your server. `LANG=C` and `es/C/LC_MESSAGES` is weird.

Comment: No, I haven't installed in my server es_ES.UTF-8 or es.UTF-8, I don't needed. I want to use default C to allow to load any language from .mo file without check system availables.

Comment: @Lito, this is not possible. You have to install all locales on the server.